# How to configure azure Web app container graceful shutdown

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I use the azure web app as a docker container host, and I want to configure the docker container or the web app for reacting to SIGTERM messages

I found only this:

When a shutdown is initiated, the container host sends a SIGTERM message to your container. The code implemented in the container can respond to this operating system-level message to handle termination.

form https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/application-lifecycle-management#shutdown

But how exactly do I need to configure a web app or container?
I don't understand.
I trying to use something like this as entrypoint.sh

```
    #!/bin/bash

# Function to gracefully stop the processes and clean up
cleanup() {
    echo "Received termination signal. Stopping processes gracefully..."

    # Stop the app (Python)
    echo "Stopping app..."
    kill $python_pid

    # Stop the Bot (Java)
    echo "Stopping Bot"
    kill $java_pid

    # Wait for the processes to be terminated
    wait $python_pid
    wait $java_pid

    echo "All processes have been stopped. Exiting..."
    exit 0
}

# Trap termination signal and call the cleanup function
trap 'cleanup' SIGTERM

# Start ML app
cd /app
echo "Starting app..."
gunicorn --log-level debug --access-logfile - --error-logfile - -b :5000 wsgi:app &
python_pid=$!

# Start Slack Bot
cd /bot
echo "Starting Bot."
java -jar hrbs.jar &
java_pid=$!

# Wait for any of the processes to finish
wait -n $python_pid $java_pid

# Cleanup on error exit (should not reach this point, as we expect termination signal to be sent)
cleanup
```

Comment: You're referencing the Azure Container Apps documentation while you're tagging Azure Web Apps/App Service. What service are you actually using?

Comment: @CSharpRocks Azure app service configured for docker container

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web App automatically handles SIGTERM signals for gracefully shutting down the container.

- You are on a right track that configuring entrypoint.sh is a good practice. set the this entrypoint.sh file inside the directory of you main application file.
- Set the execution permission inside the container `chmod +x entrypoint.sh`

**Path directory:**

[image]

**Dockerfile:**

```
# Use an appropriate base image for your application
FROM python:3.8

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy your application files to the container
COPY app/ /app
COPY entrypoint.sh /app

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

# Grant execute permissions to entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/entrypoint.sh

# Expose the port your application listens on
EXPOSE 5000

# Set the entrypoint to run your entrypoint.sh script
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

- If you add any packages to you application as per your requirement configure **`requirements.txt`**.

Once your application is ready convert to image and send to container as below.

[image]

Then, Create a webapp in portal configure publish option as Docker container as below.

[image]

Once deployment is done. Go to the "Settings" section of your Web App, select "Container settings," and ensure that "Graceful shutdown" is enabled. check the container created in docker desktop and run it.

Comment: Hi, could you please share the screenshot from the web app, because I don't see the "setting" tab, I see only the "configuration" tab